# UITextView setAttributedText and disable scroll to top

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have uitextview with about 5 lines and need to scroll. I also need to setAttributedText. Problem is that after I did that, uitextview always scroll back to top.

```
[self.txtPost setAttributedText:self.mutableAttributedString];
```

I need to setAttributedText without scrolling back to top. May I know how to do?

Answer (score 4):

It is due to ios 8 feature. It will always scroll to top after setText or setAttributedText.

To prevent that, I need to write this.

```
textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be the case. Make sure the font is same in both cases i.e. while setting normal string and attributed string.

Use this code as a reference:

**Normal String-**

```
self.textview.text= @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, attributed string eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, attributed string quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi attributed string ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
self.textview.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
```

**Attributed String-**

```
NSMutableAttributedString* string= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, attributed string eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, attributed string quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi attributed string ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,50)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(50,100)];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length)];
[self.textview setAttributedText:string];
```

Comment: I use setAttributedText so that font will not be same for my input string. How shall I do?

Comment: In my case the scroll position remains same but if there is any difference in font then a little jump in scroll position can be seen. I don't think it can be fixed unless you manually scroll the textview programatically.